# Best way to implement DRY in this example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What is the best way to create a reusable read method in this example. I have two chunks of code that do two things in common, read file and check for a certain regex pattern. I want to separate these two tasks in a separate method so that i can re-use it.I started refactoring but it is not working, i am still learning how to use blocks effeciently.Can somebody show me the best way to do this? Thank you in advance.

method1

```
   File.readlines(file) do |line|
    if line.match(/@/)
    line.split.each do |word| 
    if word.include?("@")
    puts word
      end

     end
  end
```

method2

```
     File.readlines(file) do |line|
     if line.match(/$hello/)
     line.split(',').each do |word|
     puts word.split('.')[0][0..6]

     end
    end 
    end
```

Re-use method

```
    def read_file file, pattern
    File.readlines(file) do |line|
    if line.match (pattern)
      #not sure what to return here
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem, but this code should help you to understand how to work with blocks and do what you want.

```
def f file, pattern
  File.readlines(file).each do |line|
    if line.match (pattern)
      yield line
    end
  end
end

f('text.txt', /@/) do |line| 
  line.split.each do |word| 
    if word.include?('@')
      puts word
    end
  end
end

f('text.txt', /^hello/) do |line|
  line.split(',').each do |word|
    puts word.split('.')[0][0..6]
  end
end
```

Also you may use `&block` as a third parameter of the function, and then instead of `yield` you may write `block.call line`.

Comment: Thank you,I appreciate it speransky

Comment: Word is not being printed out though.Did you test it to see if it works on your end?